Wiring is a bit confusing
My box in the wall has two lights coming in from above my table. The wires coming out are black white and ground. My old switch is two black wires and green. The two whites are capped. The two black run into the switch. Trying to change color from white two black on switch. New switch comes with a black wire red wire red wire with white strip and ground. How do I hook this new one up.

Sounds like you have either a 3-way switch, or a smart switch... Make and model?

Lutron. Skylark

There's apparently several different kinds of Lutron Skylarks. Does the switch have a model number? Does it come with an instruction sheet? The web-search I did for Lutron Skylark eventually led me to an easy-to-work-out instruction PDF with descriptions of existing switches and the black/red/red-with-white-stripe wires and what to do with them. Please edit your question to ask what help you need interpreting the instruction sheet.

Scl-153p is the number

I hooked it up as per PDF and it burned it up. Most be missing something

you made a short circuit by using white on the switch

Can you post a picture showing the wires and the way you connected them to the switch?

Your description is confusing. Lights can't come into a box. Did you mean two cables, or one cable serving two lights? What does "from white two black on switch" mean? Please revise to be more clear and correct any word usage issues.

You stated: "Trying to change color from white two black on switch."  Why ?  Don't do it. It is not necessary.
First, be sure the power is off at the breaker servicing this circuit.
Tie the 2 white wires together with a wire nut and tuck them in the back of the box.
The green wire on the switch is connected to the bare ground wires.
The black wire on the switch is connected to the black wire in the box that provides power from the breaker.  You need to identify which of the 2 black wires this is.  Either use a non contact tester or a multimeter.
The remaining black wire in the box is attached to the solid red wire on the switch. This provides power to the light when the switch/dimmer is turned on.
The red wire with a white stripe is not used in your application. It is for a 3way switch situation, to be used as a traveler. Cut any  bare wire off and put a wire nut on the end. Tuck it in the box.
With this wiring done the switch/dimmer will turn on and dim the light.
